# OOP Python Tic Tac Toe update class for board

Tags: python, oop

This is the beginning of a tic-tac-toe game using some OOP.  I'm running into trouble updating the instance variables for the class (if I have my terminology right).  As I go through the while loop, I'm not storing entries.

I've read through the documentation and have a little experience with OOP, I've tried a few other approaches, but I can't tell if my premise is wrong and I need to head in another direction or if I'm a line away from a solution.  (I hope this formats correctly!)

```
class Board:

    def __init__(self, square1=' ', square2=' ', square3=' ', square4=' ', square5=' ', square6=' ', square7=' ', square8=' ', square9=' '):
        self.square1 = square1
        self.square2 = square2
        self.square3 = square3
        self.square4 = square4
        self.square5 = square5
        self.square6 = square6
        self.square7 = square7
        self.square8 = square8
        self.square9 = square9
        self.grid = '\nSQUARES ARE 0-8, TOP LEFT TO BOTTOM RIGHT, TRAVEL HORIZONTALLY\n   |   |   \n '+square1+' | '+square2+' | '+square3+'  \n___|___|___\n   |   |   \n '+square4+' | '+square5+' | '+square6+'  \n___|___|___\n   |   |   \n '+square7+' | '+square8+' | '+square9+'  \n   |   |   '


game=Board()

print(game.grid)

while True:
    entry = input('Please enter a number\n')
    if entry == '0':
        update = Board(square1='X')

    elif entry == '1':
        update = Board(square2='X')

    elif entry == '2':
        update = Board(square3='X')

    elif entry == '3':
        update = Board(square4='X')

    elif entry == '4':
        update = Board(square5='X')

    elif entry == '5':
        update = Board(square6='X')

    elif entry == '6':
        update = Board(square7='X')

    elif entry == '7':
        update = Board(square8='X')

    elif entry == '8':
        update = Board(square9='X')

    print(update.grid)
```

Comment: learn the concept of the list. It will make your problem way easier

Comment: There's a programming rule called DRY, for "Don't Repeat Yourself".  Whenever you find yourself writing very similar lines of code over and over, it's a sign you're working at too low a level and need to move up.  In this case, are you familiar with the Python `list` and/or `dict` data types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I think is the shortest way to go from your current code to a working example.

This definitely isn't how I'd recommend to write this code from scratch - the other answers show how you can use Python lists and methods/functions to do it cleanly.

But it may be useful to see the things I've changed and compare it to your original version. I think you are having trouble with how to use classes (in places like `update = Board(square2='X')`).

```
class Board:

    def __init__(self, square1=' ', square2=' ', square3=' ', square4=' ', square5=' ', square6=' ', square7=' ', square8=' ', square9=' '):
        self.square1 = square1
        self.square2 = square2
        self.square3 = square3
        self.square4 = square4
        self.square5 = square5
        self.square6 = square6
        self.square7 = square7
        self.square8 = square8
        self.square9 = square9

    def grid(self):
        message = '\nSQUARES ARE 0-8, TOP LEFT TO BOTTOM RIGHT, TRAVEL HORIZONTALLY\n   |   |   \n ' + self.square1+' | '+self.square2+' | '+self.square3+'  \n___|___|___\n   |   |   \n '+self.square4+' | '+self.square5 + ' | ' + self.square6+'  \n___|___|___\n   |   |   \n ' + self.square7 + ' | ' + self.square8+' | ' + self.square9+'  \n   |   |   '
        print(message)


game=Board()

print(game.grid)

while True:
    entry = raw_input('Please enter a number\n')
    if entry == '0':
        game.square1='X'

    elif entry == '1':
        game.square2='X'

    elif entry == '2':
        game.square3='X'

    elif entry == '3':
        game.square4='X'

    elif entry == '4':
        game.square5='X'

    elif entry == '5':
        game.square6='X'

    elif entry == '6':
        game.square7='X'

    elif entry == '7':
        game.square8='X'

    elif entry == '8':
        game.square9='X'

    print(game.grid())
```

Comment: Great!  I had actually tried the game.square(n)='X', but was missing print(game.grid()), as well as a few other things.

I realize my code isn't ideal, but at this early stage in my development, should I work toward rewriting it?  Thus far, I've taken the track of writing as best I can, then amending my code, unless it's an absolute disaster.

Is there any consensus on this?

Thanks, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

OOP stands for object oriented programming. In this case, your object is the `Board`. The `class` is like the template you use to create other boards, using:

```
new_board = Board()
```

From that point on, you have to work with your `new_board`, which is an *instance* of a `Board`. What I mean here is that in your `while` loop, your creating new boards when you do `update = Board...` instead of modifying your previous one.

In order to do that you should add *methods* to your board. Those are functions that will modify the board. Also, you should store the data within your class using some other kind of data structure, such as a list. For example:

```
class Board:

    def __init__(self):
        self.squares = [0] * 9

    def check_square(self, number):
        self.squares[number] = 'X'

    def print_grid(self):
        # printing code here

game=Board()
game.print_grid()

while True:
    entry = input('Please enter a number\n')

    game.check_square(int(entry))
    game.print_grid()
```

I hope you get the feeling.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, but I think the elements of `squares` should stick to one datatype, instead of sometimes being `int`s and sometimes strings. You need an empty value, a cross value and a circle value, so having strings `'-', 'X' and 'O'` is probably a good place to start.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I didn't realize I was using an integer as the default value (`[0]`) and then a string when the square is checked. Things like this do not happen in serious programming languages like C++... just kidding :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach:

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fields = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

    def update(self, n, seed):
        self.fields[(n / 3)][n % 3] = seed

    def printBoard(self):
        print
        for l in self.fields:
            for e in l:
                print e,
            print

b = Board()

b.printBoard()

b.update(1, 'X')
b.printBoard()

>>> 0 0 0
    0 0 0
    0 0 0

    0 X 0
    0 0 0
    0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you take the aproach described here:

http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/12/python-tictactoe-tk-minimax-ai/

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments you should use list rather than declaring 9 different variables
Also the problem you are facing is that you are not updating the game board rather you  are creating a new board object that is initialised with some square set to 'X'`

You can use a setter function in the `Board Class`

```
class Board(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.block=[]
        for i in range(0,9):
            self.block.append(" ")

    def print_Grid(self):
        #print self.block
        # print in a required manner using list self.block

    def setBlock(self,index):
        self.block[index]='X'

obj=Board()#create board

while True:
    entry = input('Index of grid to be filled\n')
    obj.setBlock(entry)
    obj.print_Grid()
```

This is the basic method by which you can achieve your goal...
Also you can google about `setter` and `getter` functions.